# how to put values of edit texts in the dialogue box

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

[image]I want to give the output, which was entered by the user in EditText, in a detailed manner in a separate dialog box, by using the values of those entered values in the edittext. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
EditText editText1,editText2,editText3;
Button btn,btn2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calculate();
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            String s = " (Result) ";
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Detailed Output is");
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("(The code should be like as follows)\n\n"+"sum of entered number is:"+s+"\n"+"multiply of entered number is:"+s+"\n"+"subtraction of entered number is:"+s)

                    .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });
}
    public void calculate() {

        String a = editText1.getText().toString();
        String b = editText2.getText().toString();
        editText3.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)+ Integer.parseInt(b))+"\n"+String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)* Integer.parseInt(b))+"\n"+String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)-Integer.parseInt(b)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain well what is your problem? Do you want to show the sum, multiplication and subtraction of the two numbers entered in editText1 and editText2, inside the AlertDialog message?

Comment: @ValentinoS.   yes..u understood exactly what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try this way:

First, declare your two EditText (those you want to sum, subtract and multiply the values, etc.) as final inside the onCreate() method of your MainActivity:

```
final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

Second, try this code for your `btn2.setOnClickListener`:

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        int myNum_one, myNum_two, myNum_three;

        try {

            myNum_one = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
            myNum_two = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

            String s = "Sum of entered number is: %d \n multiply of entered number is: %d \n subtraction of entered number is: %d";
            int sum = myNum_one + myNum_two;
            int multiply = myNum_one * myNum_two;
            int subtraction = myNum_one - myNum_two;
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Detailed Output is");
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(String.format(s, sum, multiply, subtraction))
                  .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            Log.d("TAG","Could not parse " + nfe);
        } 

    }
});
```

Comment: i am not able to make the EditText as final as it is giving errors..and the second thing if i am using without making final, then also it is providing error at .setNuetralButton....please go through my code once again if possible, as you are almost there..

Comment: I tried that too...but dialogue box is not opening and it is crashing if i click on dialog button

Answer (score 1):

you can user String.Format to format your string with input parameters.

```
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(String.format("(The code should be like as follows)\n\n"+"sum of entered number is:%s\n multiply of entered number is:%s \n subtraction of entered number is:%s"),editText1.getText().toString(), editText2.getText().toString(), editText3.getText().toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

first don't write msg in code because if you want translate your app to different language you don't have option, better practice is used strings.xml file to storage your string

good method is add your msg to strings.xlm file

```
<string name="myMsg">The code should be like as follows)\n\n sum of entered number is:%1$s \n multiply of entered number is:%2$s\n subtraction of entered number is:%3$s</string>
```

and if you want use this in code:

```
String msg = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.myMsg), editText1,editText2,editText3));
```

and add to dialog:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg);
```