# how to put values of EditText in the dialogue box

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

[image]

I want to give the output, which was entered by the user in `EditText`, in a detailed manner in a separate dialog box, by using the values of those entered values in the `EditText`. Any help will be appreciated.

Ex-when a user enters "abc", it prints only their ascii values in the `EditText`..now I want these values to be used and the user gets full details of these values in a seperate dialogue box as mentioned in the SAMPLE image...

Here is the code:

```
    btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

    final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String a = editText1.getText().toString();
            byte b[]=a.getBytes();
            char ch[]=a.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
            {

                editText2.setText(editText2.getText()+" "+String.valueOf(b[i]));
            }
        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Ascode.this);


                String a;
                a = editText1.getText().toString();
                String s[]=a.split("\\s");
                byte b[]=a.getBytes();
                    char ch[]=a.toCharArray();

                    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
                    {
                        s[i] = "Value of: \n"+ch[i]+ "is" +b[i]+"\n";
                    }

                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Detailed Output is");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(String.format(s[i]))
                            .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi :) I don't understand well what is your problem here, can you explain well?Ah.. can you accept the best answer of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032049/how-to-put-values-of-edit-texts-in-the-dialogue-box/42032506?noredirect=1 ? Thanks!

Comment: @ValentinoS. I have added a picture to be more specific..it is quite same as earlier question, which u resolved...and I have accepted your previous answer as well...

Comment: @ValentinoS. I have added an example too to be more clear...

Comment: @Rohan tell your requirement in a single line !

Comment: @Charuක when a user enters "ABC", it prints 65 66 67 in the edittext..I want to give full details of these values in a seperate dialogue box..u can refer the image..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to put values of edit texts in the dialogue box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032049/how-to-put-values-of-edit-texts-in-the-dialogue-box)

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I have tried, but in vain...as in this case i am using an array of string and which is why I have stuck...

Comment: @Rohan check my answer and tell me what do you want to know extra!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy @Rohan, sorry for the delay but I was off. So, here is my solution, I hope I understood well your problem. This is the code for btn2:

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Ascode.this);


            String a;
            a = editText1.getText().toString();

            a = a.replace(" ","");
            byte b[] = a.getBytes();
            String[] s = a.split("(?!^)");
            String message = "";

            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            {
                message += "Value of: \n"+s[i]+ " is " +b[i]+"\n";
            }

            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Detailed Output is");
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

- May be you convert your value.But before that you get that value (user input),Right? So keep that/use that.
- You know how to display an Alert right? Use a custom Alert Dialogue use couple of views there to set the text/data you captured (if you only want to show them no need of using Edit Text views there) from the user input and you are good to go.

Example:
*dialog_layout.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:hint="textViewOne"
        android:id="@+id/textViewOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:hint="textViewTwo"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:hint="textViewThree"
        android:id="@+id/textViewThree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*Alert*

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Details Out Put");
    TextView textViewOne = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewOne);
    textViewOne.setText("One"); <--- here set the text you got! Insted of One like editText1.getText().toString()
    // add other two text views as the same way
    builder.setView(dialogLayout);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    builder.show()
```

*Note: I've used `TextView`s  since i do not see a point of editing a text that you only want to display ! If you want replace them with `EditText` views*

---

I am not quite sure what your algorithm is.But if you want to convert String to an ascii byte array this is the whole code you need to convert as well as set the value for a one input.

```
String stringOfEditTextOne = editTextOne.getText().toString();
byte[] biteArrayOne = stringOfEditTextOne.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.println("BiteArrayOut >" + biteArrayOne.toString());

// now you only need to set this value
// textViewOne.setText(biteArray.toString());
```

---

Edit  : Here is all you need to do

```
ArrayList<String> userInputOneAsciiArrayListString = new ArrayList<String>();
//...
String userInputOne = "Charu"; // use edit text and get the user input
for (int i = 0; i< userInputOne.length() ; i++){
     char character =  userInputOne.charAt(i);  // get each character
     int ascii = (int) character;
     userInputOneAsciiArrayListString.add(ascii+"");
}
System.out.println("ascii Char Value >"+userInputOneAsciiArrayListString);
String formatStringForFirsInput = userInputOneAsciiArrayListString.toString()
        .replace(",", "")  //remove the commas
        .replace("[", "")  //remove the right bracket
        .replace("]", "")  //remove the left bracket
        .trim();           //remove trailing spaces from partially initialized arrays

// now directly set this formatStringForFirsInput value to textView
```

Comment: I want the desired values, which will come through loop and passing an array of string(that i have mentioned in the .java file in my post). I dont want just the text in the dialog box...i think you should again go through my post once again to be more clear.. thanks!!!

Comment: @Rohan Okay papa now tell me what went wrong for you? **when a user enters "ABC", it prints 65 66 67 in the edittext..I want to give full details of these values in a seperate dialogue box..u can refer the image** this was your requiremt

Comment: @ Charuක If i follow your code, I will be able to print the text only in the dialog box..As i am getting values from user, so my motive to take values from edit text entered by user and set these value in dailogbox. eg-if he enters "AB", it should be like Value for A is:65, Value for B is:66....yes that is the requirement, I am able to get them in the edittext but not in the dialgbox..

Comment: @Rohan of course! I was saying the same thing!! tell me where user type the value, where you save/ add that value then i will tell you how to set text that . Its simple as that

Comment: I have made two edittexts..user type text one edit text and i show the desired output(values of those text) on the other edittext...eg-if user puts ABC in one edittext, I am showing only 65 66 67 in the other edittext...

Comment: yes, I am able to do that...logic and everything besides dialog box is okay...but showing these values with addition of some details in a dialoguebox is the problem i am facing..

Comment: Easiest way for you  is if you don;t have much views use them manually of first textView  > `textViewOne.setText( "Value of:" +ch[0]+ "is" +b[0]);` why dont you use it in that way? and for the second one `secondViewOne.setText( "Value of:" +ch[1]+ "is" +b[1]);`

Comment: For a small task you are doing extra work which finally makes you confuse !

Comment: As I am getting values from user, I am not aware of how much long string he is going to enter, and that's why i have used the loop to fulfil my requirements. if i use ch[0]+ "is" +b[0] & ch[1]+ "is" +b[1], I will only be able to print the values of AB only...now if he enters abcdefghij and so on, i will not be able to display all the values of the entered string.

Comment: I dont understand your logic, this is my final question tell me this. I am a user I type Charu on your first edit text View now when i click that button what do you want to show in the field related to my input which is editTextOne

Comment: i am displaying ascii code of the entered text. eg-if u enter Charu in edittextone, it will show the ascii values of Charu(ie 97 104 97 114 117) in the edittexttwo...and i am able to do it quite succefully so...challenging part is to show these values on the dialogue box with more details(ie:Value for C is 97, value for h is 104, value for a is 97, value for r is 114, value for u is 117)..

Comment: @Rohan If you use US_ASCII (updated that part ) format that is only 2 lines, all you need may be it helps may be not, hope you get something from me !

Comment: @Rohan update the answer check the edit part it will give you the exact thing you were looking for Have fun